# How to hide label when its text is nil in swift

Tags: swift, null, label

I am adding badgeLabel to cartBtn.. here **I am unable to convert integer to string and string to integer to hide badgeLabel if its count is 0**

code:

```
    public var badgeText: String? {
    didSet {
        let wasNil = NSString(string: badgeText ?? "0").integerValue <= 0
        badgeLabel.isHidden = badgeText == nil
        badgeLabel.text = badgeText
        setSize()

        if animated {

            let animations: () -> Void = { [weak badgeLabel] in
                badgeLabel?.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
            }

            if wasNil {
                badgeLabel.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           delay: 0.2,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 0.3,
                           options: UIView.AnimationOptions(),
                           animations: animations,
                           completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
public var badgeBackgroundColor = UIColor.red {
    didSet {
        badgeLabel.backgroundColor = badgeBackgroundColor
    }
}
```

like this adding count to label

```
 let cartQty = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "cartCount")
 cartBtn.badgeText = cartQty as? String
```

here if `cartBtn.badgeText` is nil then also i am showing `badgeLabel` but if its nil i don't want to show `badgeLabel`.. how to do hat.. please do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually using the animations when `wasNil` is true. Also don't use NSString, it's an older API now and you can just use a easy `Int` initializer to go from `String` to `Int`.

Here's some updated code:

```swift
public var badgeText: String? {
    didSet {
        // changing this variable name for clarity.
        let isTextAString: Bool = Int(badgeText ?? "") == nil

        badgeLabel.isHidden = isTextAString
        badgeLabel.text = badgeText

        setSize()

        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                           delay: 0.2,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 0.3,
                           options: UIView.AnimationOptions()) {

                self.badgeLabel?.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)

                // You can just do this `if` statement inside the animation block

                if isTextAString {
                     self.badgeLabel.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
                }

            } completion: { (_) in }
        }
    }
}
```